# How to get multiple relationships Data in My Laravel Vue Project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a 3 model "User","Review","ReviewReplay"

in user Model

```
    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Review');
    }

    public function reviewReplys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ReviewReply');
    }
```

In Review Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function reviewReplys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ReviewReply');
    }
```

in Review Replay Model

```
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function review()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Reviews');
    }
```

in My Controller

```
public function getReview($id)
    {
        $review= Review::where('product_id',$id)->with('user','reviewReplys')->paginate(10);
        return response()->json($review);
    }
```

Now here I run Review foreach loop and here I need review.reviewReplay.user information. How I Get The Review Replay User information inside Review Foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below.

```
$review= Review::where('product_id',$id)->with(['reviewReplys.user'])->paginate(10);
```

`with(['reviewReplys.user'])` --> it will make connection between **Review** model to **reviewReplys** model +

**reviewReplys** model to **User** model